# Ordering more than one of the same item

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like for my customers to be able to order more than one of the same item without having to add an item.  Instead of a check box, I would like to add a quantity box.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can add a quantity box:

1. Select Assign Prices (but not Collect Payment) for the Choice field containing your items, and assign prices to each item.
2. Add a Number field (Integer type) called Quantity, and set the default value of the Quantity field to 1.
3. Add a Price field to calculate the price based on the selected item and quantity. Set the Amount to something like: `=MyChoiceField_Amount * Quantity`
4. Set the Item Name of the Price field to something like: `=MyChoiceField`, and set the Item Description to something like: "Quantity"
5. Set the "Show This Field" option of the Price field to "Never" if you only want the total to appear in the order, and not the form itself.